# Spring WebMvcSecurityConfiguration is Deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I started configuring security for a Spring boot application but WebMvcSecurityConfiguration is marked deprecated.

Is there a better alternative to configure security?

I'm using spring boot 1.5.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From official documentation

> As of Spring Security 4.0, @EnableWebMvcSecurity is deprecated. The replacement is @EnableWebSecurity which will determine adding the Spring MVC features based upon the classpath.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/mvc.html